# How to do a Backup and Restore of Cassandra Nodes in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, backup, datastax, snapshot

We have 2  *m3 large* instances that we want to do backup of. How to go about it? 
The data is in the SSD drive.
nodetool snapshot will cause the data to be written back to the same SSD drive . Whats the correct procedure to be followed?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use nodetool snapshot to back up your data on each node.  You will have to have enough SSD space to account for snapshots and the compaction frequency.  Typically, you would need about 50% of the SSD storage reserved for this.  There are other options as well.  Datastax Opscenter has backup and recover capabilities that use snapshots and help automate some of the steps but you will need storage allocated for that as well.  [Talena](http://www.talena-inc.com) also has a solution for back/restore & test-dev management for Cassandra (and other data stores like HDFS, Hive, Impala, Vertica, etc.). It relies less on Snapshots by making copies off-cluster and simplifying restores.